# How to use right_pad function with undefined values?

Tags: freemarker

I have a list of elements in my FTL Script, now I need to use the function right_pad with these elements. This works with elements which exists but if an element does not exist, the right_pad function does nothing.

Example

```
 [${(listofElements["fieldThatExists"]?right_pad(5))!""}]
```

Assuming the value of the field is 123 this will output

```
[123  ]
```

This field does not exist:

```
 [${(listofElements["notExistingField"]?right_pad(5))!""}]
```

Then the output is

```
[]
```

But I expected this output

```
[     ]
```

How can I retrieve the expected value if the field is undefined. I know I can put

```
 !"     "
```

instead of

```
 !""
```

but this not enough because the value of right pad is not constant (not always 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `right_pad` outside:

```
[${(listOfElements["fieldThatExists"]!"")?right_pad(5)}]
```

But since the right-hand operand of `!` is optional, there's shorter version:

```
[${listOfElements["fieldThatExists"]!?right_pad(5)}]
```